# R, Sweave, Hmisc: pretty-print numbers

Tags: sweave, r

I'm creating a LaTeX tables based on a matrix in R using the 'latex' function of the Hmisc package.

```
dat = matrix(c(1000, 100, 10000, 10000), 2)
latex(dat, file='')
```

This works (as expected) perfectly.

Additionally I would like to use

```
prettyNum(dat, '.')
```

to format the numbers in a more readable way. For example:

```
 100 -->   100 
1000 --> 1.000
```

Is there a simple way to combine these functions without breaking the (automatic!) table alignment ('r' for numbers instead of 'l' for character)?

Comment: knitr has more flexibility than Sweave. Have you looked to see if it supports something like this?

Comment: I stumbled over knitr some weeks ago, but build my current documents mainly with Sweave. Perhaps I'll try to switch in future projects.
+1 for this tip :)

Comment: @scottkosty `knitr` looks *very* interesting, although I don't think it solves this problem directly; the problem here lies with Hmisc's (unavoidable) dependence on particular LaTeX packages.  But I may be missing something.  If you're familiar with `knitr` maybe you could work up a solution using it?

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm just starting to dig below the surface of `knitr` so I won't be able to make an attempt. My guess is that you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The `Hmisc` package has been updated, and now allows for arbitrary column specifications. Please see Boris' answer for a simple solution.

**Original Answer**

One of the problems with the way most R packages generate tables is that they are not easy to adapt to changing functionality within LaTeX. The standard for pretty printing numbers and tables *within LaTeX* is the `siunitx` package, which `Hmisc` doesn't support. There is no simple way around this if you are generating the tables using Sweave unless you post-edit your resultant `.tex` file.

However, if you are willing to do that, it's not that difficult to generate tables with `Hmisc` and then replace its `r` columns with the `S` column type defined by `siunitx`.

Here's a example:

**.Rnw file**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{group-separator={.},group-minimum-digits={3},output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
library("Hmisc")
dat <-  matrix(c(1000, 100, 10000, 10000,3.145,1700.42), 2)
@
<<echo=false,results=tex>>=
latex(dat,table=F,center='centering',file='',
  booktabs=T,numeric.dollar=F,colheads=c("Col A","Col B","Col C"),colnamesTexCmd="bfseries")
@

\end{document}
```

**Output .tex file**

When you Sweave this file, you produce the `.tex` file which contains the following line:

```
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
```

If you manually change this to:

```
\begin{tabular}{SSS}
```

the final `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{group-separator={.},group-minimum-digits={3},output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}
\begin{document}

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> library("Hmisc")
> dat <-  matrix(c(1000, 100, 10000, 10000,3.145,1700.42), 2)
\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}
% latex.default(dat, table = F, center = "centering", file = "",      booktabs = T, numeric.dollar = F, colheads = c("Col A", "Col B",          "Col C"), colnamesTexCmd = "bfseries") 
%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{SSS}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Col A}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Col B}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Col C}\tabularnewline
\midrule
1000&10000&   3.145\tabularnewline
 100&10000&1700.420\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Now `siunitx` can do its magic, and the output is the following:

[image: output of modified tex file]

Comment: It is much simpler with the new version of Hmisc - see my answer...

Comment: @Boris.  That's great.  It makes Hmisc even more useful.  Thanks for posting your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Actually the new version of Hmisc has the parameter `col.just`, so you do not need to edit the tex file

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{group-separator={.},group-minimum-digits={3},
  output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
library("Hmisc")
dat <-  matrix(c(1000, 100, 10000, 10000,3.145,1700.42), 2)
@
<<echo=false,results=tex>>=
latex(dat,table=F,center='centering',file='',
  booktabs=T,numeric.dollar=F,colheads=c("Col A","Col B","Col C"),
      colnamesTexCmd="bfseries", col.just=c("S","S","S"))
@

\end{document}
```

[image]