# Importing mathematical calculations processed by an external file

Tags: math-mode, import

I usually work with software called Wolfram Mathematica. With this software I perform mathematical calculations and get their results.

I usually do the following:

`Button Right Click -> Copy As -> LaTeX`

[image]

With that I get my TeX code.

**I would like to know if there is any script (macro) or if it is possible to compile a TeX file so that it can import this data from an external file.**

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
\({\int_0^{10} \left(x^2 + 3x - \frac{1}{3}\right) \, dx}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\(480\)
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unclear exactly what you're asking to do. If you use *Mathematica*'s Copy As > LaTeX, then you just paste the successive Input and Output expressions to the same `.txt` file; from there you can copy them and paste into the LaTeX source file. Otherwise, how would you expect some (LaTeX editor/IDE?) script to know where to place what?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to look into the `sagetex` package. That gives you access to an open source computer algebra system version (similar to Mathematica). Search this site for various examples, such as [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283081/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-transpose-a-matrix-written-in-latex/283116#283116).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My concern is to change information in the calculations software and forget to paste the new results into the TeX editor. I would like to know some possible solution for this.

Comment: Then it really sound like `sagetex`. Changing some entries in the matrix will result in the CAS Sage calculating a new transpose and calculating a new product. You don't have to update the result--it does it for you. See link I gave in earlier comment. The documentation for the package is [here](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf).

Comment: I would expect some script that I could link a certain line of TeX code (through a command from some package) with a specific line of code from the other program.

Comment: @DJP Thanks for the comments and I'll study about what you indicated