# number separator formatting with ragged right positioning using siunitx, R, Hmisc::latex

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, r

I found Boris's suggestion to use `siunitx` to achieve number formatting in `Hmisc::latex` tables to almost be exactly what I was looking for: 
[R, Sweave, Hmisc: pretty-print numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46700/r-sweave-hmisc-pretty-print-numbers/52161#52161)

However, if you look closely at the table, the number columns line up poorly with the column labels. This is worse when using multicolumn labels (e.g., cgroup). In looking at the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) (page 15, table 9) for siunitx, I think this is because it is centering the numbers at the decimal point.

Is it possible to use the number formatting functions of `siunitx` but justify the columns as `\raggedleft` (right aligned) within a call to `Hmisc::latex`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out the option `table-format` on page 51 of the documentation.

I can illustrate with this example based on the answer you linked to.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{group-separator={.},group-minimum-digits={3},
  output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<>>=
library("Hmisc")
dat <-  matrix(c(1000, 100, 10000, 10000,3.145,1700.42), 2)
@
<<echo=false,results=tex>>=
latex(dat,table=F,center='centering',file='',
  booktabs=T,numeric.dollar=F,colheads=c("Col A","Col B","Col C"),
      colnamesTexCmd="bfseries", col.just=c("S[table-format = 4]",
                                            "S[table-format = 5]",
                                            "S[table-format = 4.3]"))
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the reference and the example.